# Infinite while loop, can't understand why

Tags: java

I've started learning programming just recently at my university, so far we are battling with Java. Our task is to do a simulation of different processor algorithms like fcfs, sjf etc. I've tried many approaches and the one you see below is probably the least optimized. I'm aware, that this code might not be the greatest, as well as algorithm itself, but I wanted to see if it work as intended and I found a problem, that I can't really understand for a little too long and I won't be able to sleep until I find out what is wrong with it.

In the code below you will find a while loop with comment line "Why is this loop inifnite" written in caps. I have no idea why it never stops (I ran some printing tests and I know that this is the loop that is going on forever) and it is really getting on my nerves (most likely because the solution is really easy now).

Some explanation: I create a list of processes, that I then execute some methods on. Process is described by: execution time (execTime); time, that it needed to wait to start getting executed (waitTime); at what time it is ready to be executed (inTime) (but might be waiting for other process to finish executing) and id. I execute process by reducing it's execTime until it reaches 0, then I remove the process and do the same for "new first one". And this reducing part is when the program go to infinity.

Mango

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Processor {

List<Process> listOP = new ArrayList<Process>();
int processorTime = 0;
int totalWaitTime = 0;
int numberOfProcesses = 0;

public Processor(){
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        listOP.add(new Process(i));
        if(i>0)
            listOP.get(i).inTime += listOP.get(i-1).inTime + (int)((Math.random() + 0.1)*10);
        System.out.println("Proces " + (listOP.get(i).id + 1) + " czas wejścia " + listOP.get(i).inTime);
    }
}

public double fcfs(){
    numberOfProcesses = listOP.size();
    while(listOP.size() != 0){
        if(listOP.get(0).inTime > processorTime){
            for(int i=0; i<listOP.size(); i++){
                listOP.get(i).waitTime = 0;
            }
        }
            totalWaitTime += listOP.get(0).waitTime;
            while(listOP.get(0).execTime != 0){//**WHY IS THIS LOOP INFINITE**
                for(int i=1; i<listOP.size(); i++){
                    if(processorTime == listOP.get(i).inTime)
                        listOP.get(i).waitTime++;
                }
                listOP.get(0).execTime--;
                processorTime++;
            }
            processorTime++;
        listOP.remove(0);
    }
    System.out.println(totalWaitTime);
    System.out.println(numberOfProcesses);
    System.out.println(processorTime);
    System.out.println("Średni czas tego ciągu procesów: " + totalWaitTime/numberOfProcesses);
    return totalWaitTime/numberOfProcesses;
}
}
```

Comment: What value is execTime initialized to? Try changing `!=` to `>`.

Comment: When you debugged it, what value did `listOP.get(0).execTime` have? How was it changing?

Comment: can you confirm that `listOp.get(0).execTime--` works ? Can you share the java object being called in listOP.get(0) ?

Comment: @John3136 Actually I didn't think about debugging this part. Feels even worse, it should be actually first thing I check I think. It goes to really low, negative numbers.

Comment: @csirmazbendeguz That actually helped, it stops where it should now. It was initialized to some random numbers given by variation of Math.random(). Could you explain why changing to ">" helped?

Comment: @Mango It must have been initialized to a negative number (or a double using random?), never hitting 0 when decrementing it.

Comment: @csirmazbendeguz Yeah when I casted the value of execTime to (int) it actually works with "!=" as well! Thank you all for your precious time :).

Comment: The thing I would ask is the obvious: What is the definition of `execTime` in `Process` class?